# Webform views - creating a filter using date from user-submitted data

Tags: views, webforms

We have a job submissions webform. In the form, there is a "closing date" field with a calendar picker (yyyymmdd format). When the closing date passes, the submission should be removed from view.

1. I created a relationship for the *Submission Data: Expiry Date* field so it can be used as a Filter.

[image]

2. Now that I have the data available as a filter, this is where I get stuck; I need the view to filter out the submission if the *Expiry Date* has passed. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a patch for this exact functionality. Out of the box, you are right, it acts as its a straight up text field. If you were to use entityform instead of webform, I believe you would be able to do this as it uses normal drupal fields.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2527608

Answer (score 1):

*Set the operator to 'is greater than'

*Select  'An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes"'

*Set the value as "now"

Comment: Hi Bianca, thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, these values are only available to "date" fields -- for whatever reason, Drupal is not detecting this field as a date field (I suspect it is because it is user-submitted data) so these options are not available to me.